# Quartz MalformedURLException No Protocol

Tags: java, unix, quartz-scheduler

I am running a Quartz Scheduler on a Unix server that is given its schedule through a .xml file. The scheduler works when I run it locally on a tomcat server, but when I deployed it to the server I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin - 
Error scheduling jobs: no protocol: /emsapps/tbs/test/conf/QuartzSchedule.xml 
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /emsapps/tbs/test/conf/QuartzSchedule.xml
```

The schedule file is defined in quartz.properties as org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = /emsapps/tbs/test/conf/QuartzSchedule.xml

I've tried putting file:// in front of the url, but then I get a file not found error. I've tried googling and searching the Quartz forums but I can't find anything that helps. Most people say it's a white space error, but there are no spaces in the url or afterwards.

Ok, I found the solution. We had a jar file with an oracle xml parser that was somehow getting activated and trying to run the schedule file, which is why it had the no protocol issue.

Comment: Did you specify the file:// url correctly ? I am a bit of doubtful on that. Specially in UNIX case you have a root directoy instead of a drive letter on windows.

Comment: I'm not sure, I put it as file:///emsapps/tbs/test/conf/QuartzSchedule.xml, and also tried file://tbsstaging/emsapps/tbs/test/conf/QuartzSchedule.xml

Comment: We have it working on our dev server, and as far as I can tell both the quartz.properties and the QuartzSchedule.xml files are identical in both except for the url for the schedule file. The url on the dev server is /emsapps/tbs/dev/conf/QuartzSchedule.xml

Comment: might be the case is root directory is not being identified as emsapps. So the file not found error. Not sure me too.